# Erorr occured while running the npm start command?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "expo": "^1.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~10.1.4",
    "expo-location": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-permissions": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    ...
}
```

[my execution errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlTkh.png)

When running `expo start`, it is generating an error.

These are the problems I am facing please help me. Thank you. :)

Comment: Your error is suggesting you your solution. Look closely.

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands.

```
npm install
npm run start
```

Comment: same thing repeated sir. any other solution sir